# Search box doesnt stay in the container of the top header

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am just learning how to use css and bootstrap to create an website based on a psd template, problem is that i cant keep my search box inside the container and it stays in the bottom of it.

Here is my code

```css
.search-area {
  margin-top: 3px;
  text-align: right;
}

.search-area input {
  background: #333333;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: 0px solid;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="header-area1">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="top-header col-12 bg-succes">
                <div class="left-header col-8">
                    <div class="feed-area">
                        <ul>
                            <li> <a href="">Sign Up</a></li>
                            <li> <a href="">Login</a></li>
                            <li> <a href="">Rss Feed</a></li>
                            <li id="last"> <a href="">Archived News</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="right-header col-4">
                        <div class="search-area">
                            <form action="">
                                <input type="textplaceholder=" Search...">
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I want the search box to be in the right of the container in the same line as the feed-area elements. Both of them are in the same container

Comment: You have some errors in your html, please check it.

Comment: #horemo pik issue with you HTML structure. Some Div closing issue.

Comment: @Sfili_81 - you should explain the errors, so our new user understands.

Comment: @Paul you are right! For example `<input type="textplaceholder=" Search...">` should be `<input type="text" placeholder="Search...">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this HTML structure for right align to searchbox. 
Add `col-6` with `feed-area` class. And instead os this `<div class="left-header col-8">` use this `<div class="left-header row">`

```
<div id="header-area1">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="top-header col-12 bg-succes">
                    <div class="left-header row">
                        <div class="feed-area col-6">
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="">Sign Up</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="">Login</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="">Rss Feed</a>
                                </li>
                                <li id="last">
                                    <a href="">Archived News</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="right-header col-4">
                            <div class="search-area">
                                <form action="">
                                    <input type="textplaceholder=">
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

.search-area {
      margin-top: 3px;
      text-align: right; 
       }

    .search-area input {
         background: #333333;
         color: #ffffff;
         border: 0px solid;
     }

Comment: Still the right search box cannot move up in the right side of the bar it is like a part of another container wich is different from the feed-bar when you see the result , i had this issue also with another example

Comment: #horemo pik search box is the right side of your `feed-area` wrap.If you want to align it from right to left side.Use `text-align: left;` css for the `.search-area` class. If you have copy my above code or not?

Comment: @horemopik You can see in the codepen example https://codepen.io/ijazali/pen/jGKLZo 
If still any issue please tell me i will understand you about this.

Answer (score 2):

I rewrote your code to fix it. do not forget to user "row" class out of your columns in bootstrap

```
<div id="header-area1">
        <div class="container">
                <div class="top-header col-12 bg-succes">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="left-header col-8">
                            <div class="feed-area">
                                <ul>
                                    <li> <a href="">Sign Up</a></li>
                                    <li> <a href="">Login</a></li>
                                    <li> <a href="">Rss Feed</a></li>
                                    <li id="last"> <a href="">Archived News</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="right-header col-4">
                            <div class="search-area">
                                <form action="">
                                    <input type="textplaceholder=" Search...">
                                </form>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Update my answer missing of `row` before `col`

```css
.search-area {
  margin-top: 3px;
  text-align: right;
}

.search-area input {
  background: #333333;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: 0px solid;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div id="header-area1">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="top-header row bg-succes">
                <div class=" col-8">
                    <div class="feed-area">
                        <ul>
                            <li> <a href="">Sign Up</a></li>
                            <li> <a href="">Login</a></li>
                            <li> <a href="">Rss Feed</a></li>
                            <li id="last"> <a href="">Archived News</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
                <div class=" col-4">
                        <div class="search-area">
                            <form action="">
                                <input type="text" placeholder=" Search...">
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```